# What do I really need to create a single signon with DotNetOpenAuth (and google apps)?

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth, single-sign-on

I've spent the past 5 days reading up on [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) and for some reason it's just not coming to me easily...

I have a local set of users in active directory.  My web portal application already authenticates the user when they access the internal site.  I now want to add in OpenID support to allow users to click on links on their portal page to redirect and log them into remote sites that support OpenID like Google Apps.

In my reading there seems to be two ways to accomplish this task.  One would be to set up a local OpenID provider.  What other pieces do I need to create for this to work?  Do I need to create a relay partner?

The other potential method (I think) would be to authenticate to google apps and let google be the OpenID provider.  Since my portal application already creates google apps accounts this would work if it were an option...

Either way, what components to I need to create for these options?  Also, if I create a `OpenID` provider do I need to expose the server to the internet to complete the transaction?

Comment: If your users already have google apps accounts, then I would highly suggest you avoid creating your own OpenID Provider. Just make your RPs verify that in fact the assertion is from Google and regarding a user from your company.

Comment: I do have all these users in and being maintained in google apps already.  Is it possible to build an external portal site to allow my users to click on a link from within my portal page to authenticate them to another site using the google apps openid?

Comment: I should also mention that I don't necessarily have control of the "external" sites I want to validate to (but they do support OpenID).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But isn't a trivial amount of work, and not a good answer to include in a comment. :)

Comment: Can you tell me at least what pieces in dotnetopenauth I would need to code this functionality? thanks! :)

Comment: (Or would it be easier to write my own provider in this instance).  Do I need to do an RP if I am the provider?

Comment: You can [download the samples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/releases/v4.2/v4.2.2/DotNetOpenAuth-4.2.2.13055-samples.7z/download). The ones relevant to what you're doing are probably the OpenIdWebRingSsoProvider, OpenIdWebRingSsoRelyingParty, and OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/loginGoogleApps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC supports this function so well, you can follow [this sample](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc) to build for your own

Comment: That's interesting... But is it possible tobuild a portal off the remote site's OpenID information?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is can you make your site log users into remote sites using openid?

You could if the remote site supported federation. There are many ways to achieve this & they generally need cooperation between you & the remote site.

Since you say the remote site supports OpenId, all you need to do is send the user there. They then sign in using OpenId using their Google Apps id. You do not need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider just directly using the Google client libraries for OpenID. Once you have things working, you can access any services that are offered by Google and can use the client libraries to access them without having to write very much code and maintain your own libraries.

The Google+ Quickstart samples cover best practices for using OAuth v2 and the Google APIs and should get you going very quickly. Start here:

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp

The code there will get you going with OAuth and a configured API client. If you want to add support for additional API clients (Google Apps) then you would include that API client and access it exactly the same as in the example.